# Reporting in .net core with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, reporting, .net-core

Is is possible to do reporting (using crystal report or any third party tool) in .Net core with Postgres as a database?

I searched quite a lot but I couldn't find any solution to this. Need guidance in the right direction for this.

Comment: Could you provide some details on your needs? "Reporting" is too generic term. Do you need pivot tables (summary reports), or just formatted lists? Who creates a reports - end-user or IT team?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend choosing a reporting technology, which doesn't depend on your "technology stack" or vice versa.

I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services (which support many different database engines):

- generate Reports via HTTP url access
- embed Reports within Websites too
- "manage" Reports via SOAP

In fact, everything happens using ordinary HTTP requests. I could be using any technology, which speaks HTTP...

I've no idea what you're trying to achieve ("do reporting" isn't that specific, you know ;)), but maybe it helps.